# Writing platform independent Socket based binary parsing code

Tags: sockets, erlang, endianness

I have an erlang application which includes parsing of binary data from socket (both TCP and UDP). The binary data is as per some specific protocol, so my options for TCP and UDP sock is as per below:

```
TCP sock :
Opts = [binary, {packet, 0}, {reuseaddr, true},
            {keepalive, true}, {backlog, 30}, {active, false}],
```

```
UDP sock :
[binary,{active,once},{recbuf,2097152}]
```

Now, when i parse the data I get from socket, I do like this (On UNIX):

```
    << Version:4/big-unsigned-integer-unit:8,
       Length:2/big-unsigned-integer:8,
       _Rest/binary >> = Bin_event_From_Socket.
```

Now, this would give me a problem when run on LINUX as LINUX is little endian based. So, the option here for me is to convert 'big' to 'little' in the above code.

But, Erlang being a VM based language, I must be having some facility to write platform independent code. I searched the NEt but couldnt find much on it.

So, the question here is how can i write a platform independent sockaet data parsing code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `big` or `little` you can use the endianness `native`. This will default to the correct endianness of the platform you're on.

Comment: Thanks Adam. But the answer by Dmitry in the link I pasted sounds more convincing.

Comment: Ah, then I misinterpreted your question. Feel free to accept your own answer then. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I got in erlang mailing list by Dmitry.

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-May/066692.html